# How to check if my list has an item from another list(dictionary)?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in programming with python, and I've got a question which may have an easy answer.

So I have a dictionary of words which is imported from a .txt file, next my program asks you to type a sentence, and then it saves every word which you've typed into another list.

I have to write a program which checks if every word of a list named `sentence_list` is in the list which is named `words`. If the word is not present in the dictionary I have to put it in another list which is being filled by all the words that are mistyped or not in the dictionary.

For easier understanding, my program should work something like that:

```
Type your sentence:
My naeme is John, I lieve in Italy, which is beatiful country.
```

```
['naeme', 'lieve', 'beatiful']
```

This is what I could do until now:

```
words = open("dictionary.txt", encoding="latin2").read().lower().split()

sentence=input("Type your sentence: ")

import re

sentence_list = re.findall("\w+", sentence.lower())
```

I know I have to do something with for, but for is different in python that it is in Javascript, which I am familiar with.

Comment: Calling `words` a "dictionary" is mildly confusing, since it is a list and not a `{}` dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using sets**

You could use sets to find all of the words not in the dictionary list.

```
>>> set([1,2,3]).difference([2,3])
set([1])
```

Note that this will not include duplicates.

So for you, it would be something like this (if you need the result to be a list):

```
misspelled_word_list = list( set(sentence_list).difference(words) )
```

**Using for**

Since you are required to use `for`, here is an alternate (less efficient) approach:

```
misspelled_word_list = []
for word in sentence_list:
    if (not word in misspelled_word_list) and (not word in words):
        misspelled_word_list.append(word)
```

You just loop over the words in `sentence_list` and check whether they are in your `words` list or not.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's required for me to use for

Comment: I guess I should have asked you what you'd tried first since this is pretty clearly homework...

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks. But now I have to make sure that the words in my list of misspelled words don't repeat.For example: My naem is John and his naem is Mark. Word naem should be in the list of misspelled words only once. I should use if?

Comment: Yes. I checked whether `word` wasn't in the list `words` by using `if not word in words`. How could you use similar code to check whether `word` wasn't in `misspelled_word_list`?

Comment: I wrote: if word in misspelled_word_list: 
misspelled_word_list.remove(word) but now the result is [countrey, naem]
instead of [naem, countrey]

Comment: Right idea, I edited my answer to include the other `if` condition.

Comment: I finally did it. Thank you very much @MatthewAdams. What kind of literature would you recommend to me coming from javascript? I feel like a retard, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure. A little googling turned up [this page](http://hg.toolness.com/python-for-js-programmers/raw-file/tip/PythonForJsProgrammers.html). I skimmed it and it seems accurate.

Comment: Not that the right person will see this, but why the unupvote?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner using `for`, that generates a `set` of mispelled words:

```
mispelled = { word for word in sentence if word not in dictionary }
```

I've renamed your variables for clarity